# Cache invalidation in load balanced application

Tags: java, caching, wildfly, ehcache

The application I'm developing uses simple HashMaps as cache for certain objects that come from the DB. It's far from ideal, but the amount of data for these chached lists is really small (less than 100) and does not change often. This solution provides minimal overhead. When an item in one of these cached lists changes, its value is replaced in the HashMap.

We're nearing the launch date on production for this application. To provide a reasonably scalable solution, we've come with a load-balancing solution. The balancer switches between several Wildfly-nodes, which each hold the entire application, except for the DB.

The issue now is that when an cached item changes, it's only updated in one of the nodes. The change is not applied to the cache in other nodes. Possible solutions are:

- Disable the caching. Not an option.
- Use a cache server like Ehcache Server. In this way there would be one cache for all nodes. The problem however would be too much overhead due to REST calls.
- A additional web service in every node. This web service would keep track of all load-balanced nodes. When a cached value changes in a node, the node would signal other nodes to evict their caches.
- An off-the-shelf solution like Ehcache with signalling features. Does this exist?

My question is: Are there products that offer the last solution (free and with open license, commercially usable)? If not, I would implement the third solution. Are there any risks/mistakes I would have to look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risks/mistakes: Of course one major thing is data consistency. When caching data from a database I'll usually make sure I make use of transactions when updating. Usually I use a pattern like this:

```
begin transaction
invalidate cache entries in the transaction
update database
commit transaction
```

In case of a cache miss during the update happens the read needs to wait until the transaction is committed.

For your use case the typical choice is a clustered or distributed cache, like: HazelCast, Infinispan, Apache Ignite. However, somehow this seams really to heavy in your use case.

An alternative is to implement an own mechanism to publish invalidation events to all nodes. Still this is no easy task, since you may want to make sure that every node received the message, but also be fault tolerant if one nodes goes down at the same time. So you probably want to use a proper library for that, e.g. JGroups or the various MQ products.

Comment: You're probably right that something like HazelCast would be too heavy. I'll try implementing a solution with invalidation events, and look at JGroups. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Pls. comment/update here if you have some new findings. Its definitely interesting to find a lightweight solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it without JGroups or other signaling libraries. Each node has a REST endpoint to evict the cache. When a node starts up, it registers itself in a DB table with its IP, domain and a token. When it shuts down it removes its record.

When an object is updated in a node, the node evicts its cache and starts several threads that send a REST call (with its token and an object type) to all other nodes using Unirest, which in turn check the token and evict their caches. When an error is thrown, the called node is removed from the list.

It should be improved in terms of security and fault tolerance. The removal of nodes is really pessimistic now. Only after several failed attempts the node should be removed. For now, this simple solution does the job!

Comment: Did it work in long run - if any, what changes you made? Any new alternatives you have found, as of today?